# Erro no retorno de um char

Tags: c, array, funções, memória

Eu estou querendo fazer um programa que converte um número decimal para binário. Fazendo essa conversão, eu queria armazenar os números decimais num `char`. Na função é armazenado certo, mas quando eu chamo a função no `main`, está dando problema, pois eu quero igualar um `char` a outro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

//n seria o número e qtdade seria a quantidade de bits
char dec2bin(int n, int qtdade) {
// int n; // Número de entrada
 int r; // Resultado do deslocamento
 int i; // Contador

 char operadores[200] = {};

 for(i = qtdade-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // Executa a operação shift right até a
    // última posição da direita para cada bit.
    r = n >> i;

    // Por meio do "e" lógico ele compara se o valor
    // na posição mais à direita é 1 ou 0
    // e imprime na tela até reproduzir o número binário.
    if(r & 1) {
       // printf("1");
        operadores[qtdade-1-i] = '1';
    } else {
       // printf("0");
        operadores[qtdade-1-i] = '0';
    }
 }

    printf("\n");
    //printf("%s", operadores);
    return operadores;
 //system("pause");
}


int main()
{


    char operadores[200] = {};
    operadores = dec2bin(10, 5);
    printf("\n\n\n\n%s", operadores);

    printf("%s", dec2bin(10,5));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não pode retornar dados alocados dentro de uma função já que ela opera como um pilha, quando retorna o dado é desempilhado e não pode ser mais acessado (até pode em alguns casos, mas tentar acessá-lo é um erro). Ou você coloca no *heap*, ou passa o *array* criado na `main()` por referência e assim a função já usa a própria alocação ocorrida na `main()` para armazenar o que precisa.

Tem outras soluções, mas para este caso parece o mais adequado.

Inicializei o *array* que poderia causar problemas dependendo do conteúdo da memória. Não sei se o código tem outros problemas.

Coloqueis nomes mais significativos, assim comentários podem ser dispensados. Dá para simplificar ainda mais, poderia ter eliminado a variável `deslocamento`, por exemplo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

void dec2bin(char operadores[], int numero, int qtdadeBits) {
    for (int i = qtdadeBits - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int deslocamento = numero >> i;
        operadores[qtdadeBits - 1 - i] = deslocamento & 1 ? '1' : '0';
    }
}

int main() {
    char operadores[200] = { 0 };
    dec2bin(operadores, 10, 5);
    printf("%s", operadores);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/d5I1y7). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kawdlvrh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/ReturnArray.c).

Veja [O que são e onde estão o "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).